# a4j:commandButton always executes form even when execute id's given

Tags: java, jsf, richfaces

I have an `a4j:commandLink` which is supposed to execute an `a4j:outputPanel` on click. However it executes the form on click even when I have given the id's in the execute tag.

```html
<a4j:commandLink id="more_message_button" value="Load More Comments"
    action="#{feedbackAction.setFeedbackIdForExpansion(unitfeedback.feedbackId)}"
    execute="expandedList,more_message_button" href="javascript:void(0)"
    limitRender="true" render="expandedList,more_message_button">
</a4j:commandLink>`
<a4j:outputPanel layout="block" id="expandedList">
    <a4j:repeat value="#{feedbackAction.getCommentsForNextHop(unitfeedback)}"
        var="unitComment" rowKeyVar="idx">
    .
    .
    .
</a4j:outputPanel>
```

Any help on this to overide the default behavior or am I missing anything here

Regards,
Nandish

Comment: Do you mean it is rendering everything on page?

Comment: No, but the entire form gets executed in the back. Renders only what I want. But I donnt want entire form to be re executed. I want only the a4j:output panel to be re processed

Comment: have you tried using the ajaxsingle="true" ?

Answer (score 0):

Just figured out the reason:

1) If the command button is in a nested a4:repeats and has reference to the instance variable of the outerloop, it will submit the form to resolve the value when clicked.

2) Now am completely moving away from using the actions, instead using the a4 java script functions to call the required action asynchronously